# How to deal with string column contains date with only hours, minutes and seconds in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In python's pandas, I use `pd.to_datetime(data.observation_time, format="%H:%M:%S")` to convert string column that only has hours:minutes:seconds, then the result always contain the year:month:day guessed by computer like these [image]

so my question here is how to convert the string column with only hours:minutes:seconds? I don't need the year,month,and day for that column

Comment: I'd also check out `pd.to_timedelta`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df['time'] = df['dates'].dt.time
```

It will create a new column with only time extracted from the datetime column

Answer (score 1):

You are so close. Actually, the `to_datetime` function is used to transform a `string` value to a `datetime` object. So the format you provide in `to_datetime` is the **current format of your string**, how python should read the string. Like this, python know that the date is actually a `date` and not a simple `string`. [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Once this transform is done, you can **reformat the date** at your own format with the `strftime` function [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

Here an example:

```
# Import module
import pandas as pd

# Build dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["1900-01-01 01:01:00",
                            "1900-01-01 02:01:00",
                            "1900-01-01 03:31:00",
                            "1900-01-01 04:01:04",
                            "1900-01-01 11:01:00"]})
print(df)
#                   Date
# 0  1900-01-01 01:01:00
# 1  1900-01-01 02:01:00
# 2  1900-01-01 03:31:00
# 3  1900-01-01 04:01:04
# 4  1900-01-01 11:01:00

# Convert the date column (string type) to datetime type
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(df)
#                    Date
# 0 1900-01-01 01:01:00
# 1 1900-01-01 02:01:00
# 2 1900-01-01 03:31:00
# 3 1900-01-01 04:01:04
# 4 1900-01-01 11:01:00

# Reformat the date column. Here Hours:minutes:seconds
df["Date"] = df.Date.dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(df)
#        Date
# 0  01:01:00
# 1  02:01:00
# 2  03:31:00
# 3  04:01:04
# 4  11:01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

use pythons datetime objects time feature:

```
data['Time'] = [val.time() for val in data['observation_time']]
```